# Windows phone 8.1 textbox multiple click

Tags: c#, textbox, windows-phone-8.1

If a textbox has focus and I want to be able to select it again is there a way to do this.

So first click the background turns blue and while it is still selected I press again the background turns green. How do I catch the second press even though its already selected?

Comment: Do you mean the text itself or the textbox?

Comment: Just the textbox, the text itself doesn't matter as the box could be empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subscribe to the `PointerEntered` and the `SelectionChanged` events. The first one is always fired when the pointer hits the TextBox. However if it contains text and you tap on it you will eventually select the text. The `SelectionChanged` handler will take care for that.

Your XAML markup looks as follows:

```
<TextBox x:Name="tb" 
    Text="Test" 
    PointerEntered="TextBox_PointerEntered"  
    SelectionChanged="TextBox_SelectionChanged" 
    GotFocus="TextBox_GotFocus"/>
```

The code behind file contains the following code:

```
private void TextBox_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    tb.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
}

private void TextBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    tb.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
}

private void TextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    tb.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
}
```

You will have to adjust the code to your needs and take care of special cases where both `SelectionChanged` AND `PointerEntered` are fired (at this point both handlers do the same, so there's no problem).

Comment: Brilliant thank you. PointerEntered is exactly what I needed.